# python pass class object as argument

Tags: function, class, tuples

Given the following class definition:

```
 class Food:
     def __init__(self, name, taste):
        self.name = name
        self.taste = taste
```

Write a function `createFood()` that takes a list of food items as argument and creates an instance of `class Food` for each of them.  It then returns the list of instances that it has created.

Each food item in the list that is passed as argument to `createFood()` is a tuple of the form `('name', 'taste')`, so the list of food items might look like this:

`[('curry', 'spicy'), ('pavlova', 'sweet'), ('chips', 'salty')]`

The function `createFood()` takes the two elements of each tuple and passes them to the initialiser of Food.  It then collects the objects returned by the initialiser and adds them to the list that is returned by `createFood()`.

DO NOT call the function

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly what the question asks:

> Write a function createFood() that takes a list of food items as argument and creates an instance of class Food for each of them. It then returns the list of instances that it has created.

```
def createFood(fooditems):
    """takes a list of food items as argument and creates an instance 
    of class Food for each of them. It then returns the list of instances 
    that it has created.
    """
    return [Food(name, taste) for name, taste in fooditems]



createFood([('curry', 'spicy'), ('pavlova', 'sweet'), ('chips', 'salty')])
```